# Unfamiliar use of square brackets in calling a function

Tags: javascript

In the middle of this [page](http://hangar.runway7.net/javascript/guide), I find the code below.

```
var plus = function(x,y){ return x + y };
var minus = function(x,y){ return x - y };

var operations = {
  '+': plus,
  '-': minus
};

var calculate = function(x, y, operation){
    return operations[operation](x, y);
}

calculate(38, 4, '+');
calculate(47, 3, '-');
```

Now while I can trace how it works, I've never seen this use of square brackets before. It certainly doesn't look like it's creating an array or referencing a member of an array. Is this common? If so, where are some other examples?

Comment: operations is not an array. It's an object and '+' and '-' are two properties of operations object

Comment: @Itay: Almost correct, expect for that it is not an Array (JS does not know associative arrays), but an Object. And yes, `object['foo']` and `object.foo` are two ways in which object properties can be accessed in JS, but only the first one allows to use a variable in place of `'foo'`

Comment: Got this all figured out once I found a lesson on object oriented javascript. For those who are new to this question - the big concept to get is that functions can be stored or bundled inside an object. You access each function in the same way as you access any other property of an object. With square brackets. Then, since the result IS a function, you provide your arguments (if there are any) inside parentheses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a dictionary access, which is like an array, but with a key instead of a numeric index.

`operations['+']` will evaluate to the function `plus`, which is then called with the arguments `plus(x,y)`.

Comment: so defining plus and minus outside of the object's curly braces seems to be a deliberately confusing exercise. Am I right?

Comment: operations['+'] does not return anything. It is a reference to a variable function, an anonymous variable function that is.

Comment: @dwilbank, not really. A dictionary (or map) can be used to easily map  objects to input strings. This is useful for instance when you are parsing user input for instance. You simply parse any operator (e.g. '+', '-', '%', '/' and then invoke the approriate function.

Comment: So when using an object as a map it's good to keep it looking clean, then build a collection of functions outside the brackets. Okay. Thanks.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv `operations['+']` does return you the definition of the function associated with '+', doesn't it? Try `alert(operations['+'])`

Comment: Yeah, http://jsfiddle.net/SHAHJ/. That's because Function.prototype.toString does that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString Still does not mean '+' is not a reference to a variable function.

Answer (score 5):

It's called [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation). 
In JavaScript you can use it to access object properties.

Comment: I do not think object properties are relevant here.

Comment: Well, what are '+' and '-' in his code then? Object _properties_ referencing variable functions. Please read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects before downvoting.

Comment: When I tried to change the brackets to dot notation to access the property, everything failed.

Comment: That's expected. `obj.+` is a clear syntax error, `+` representing addition or concatenation, depending on the operands. `obj.'+'` would work but would lead to some pretty confusing code. So the people that define JavaScript came up with the `obj['+']` syntax.

Comment: You can only access `[a-zA-z-_]*` properties with the dot method.

Comment: This is the first time I read an explanation of dictionary access as syntactic sugar for attribute lookups (with extra possibilities for attribute names) instead of the other way round. It is certainly an interesting way of looking at things.

Comment: I did not come up with it. Do a search for "dictionary" and then for "bracket notation" in http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf (ECMA Script specifications). You'll find out there is no such thing as a "Dictionary" in ECMA Script (JavaScript follows this standard).

Answer (score 2):

here `operations` is an object where the symbols `+` and `-` refers to two functions.

`operations[operation]` will return a reference to function `plus` where value of `operation` is `+` and then the following `()` will invoke the function

Answer (score 0):

`operations` is an object and when you do `operations[property]` you will get the associated function and then you are passing the operands as x and y.

`operations['+']` is `function (x,y){ return x + y }` which is `plus`

`operations['-']` is `function (x,y){ return x - y }` which is `minus`

Comment: `operations` is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

My JavaScript book says that object properties need be **named** with arbitrary names. But '+' and '-' are not names. From the original question, it is inferred that object properties just need be **keyed**, not named.